# How to use wget with a proxy

Tags: proxy, wget

I currently have been blocked from http://www.apkmirror.com, so a `wget` produces an `ERROR 403: Forbidden`:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$ wget http://www.apkmirror.com
--2017-04-21 12:51:42--  http://www.apkmirror.com/
Resolving www.apkmirror.com (www.apkmirror.com)... 104.19.135.58, 104.19.132.58, 104.19.133.58, ...
Connecting to www.apkmirror.com (www.apkmirror.com)|104.19.135.58|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2017-04-21 12:51:42 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

I'm trying to use a proxy from https://free-proxy-list.net/ to gain access. For example, following https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Proxies.html, I've tried

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$ wget http://www.apkmirror.com@70.32.89.160:3128
--2017-04-21 12:57:56--  http://www.apkmirror.com@70.32.89.160:3128/
Connecting to 70.32.89.160:3128... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2017-04-21 12:57:59 ERROR 400: Bad Request.
```

but I get an `ERROR 400: Bad Request`. Is there anything wrong with this (attempted) usage of `wget`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the wrong method, Let me tell you.

Go to home on your server or computer using `cd ~`

then create a file using vim like `vi ~/.wgetrc`

and paste your proxy URL inside the file using as below.

```
use_proxy = on
http_proxy =  http://70.32.89.160:3128
https_proxy =  http://70.32.89.160:3128
ftp_proxy = http://70.32.89.160:3128
```

now use below command to access your blocked side.

```
wget -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=$proxy http://www.apkmirror.com
```

or try using `wget http://www.apkmirror.com` you will see below output.

```
root@ubuntu:~# wget www.apkmirror.co
--2017-04-21 08:12:45--  http://www.apkmirror.co/
Connecting to 70.32.89.160:3128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.apkmirror.co/ [following]
--2017-04-21 08:12:47--  http://www.apkmirror.co/
Connecting to 70.32.89.160:3128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 76512 (75K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.8’

100%[===================================================================================================================>] 76,512       447KB/s   in 0.2s

2017-04-21 08:12:49 (447 KB/s) - ‘index.html.8’ saved [76512/76512]
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use,this is:

```
wget -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=http://ilanni:123456@10.10.10.128:3128 http://oss.aliyuncs.com/aliyunecs/rds_backup_extract.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

start wget through socks5 proxy using tsocks:

1. install tsocks: `sudo apt install tsocks`
2. config tsocks

   ```sh
   # vi /etc/tsocks.conf

   server = 127.0.0.1
   server_type = 5
   server_port = 1080
   ```
3. start: `tsocks wget http://url_to_get`

Comment: Note that [tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/) seems to be no longer maintained.